# SumIf with Wildcard

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use a wildcard and the SumIf function or a SumProduct Function.  In one column I have different Transaction Descriptions.  I want the function to give me all the totals for adjacent cells to cells containing a key word.  I've tried the following formulas:

=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Company",Sheet5!F2:F72)))*Sheet5!G3:G71)

=SUMIF(Sheet3!F:F,"*Company",Sheet3!G:G)

Neither will return a value.

My company descriptions vary, which is why I'm trying to use the wildcard.  For example, sometimes the description in F is Company LLC - January, and sometimes its Company LLC - Parent Distribution, etc...I just need it to find all transactions with Company in the cell.

Thanks!

Comment: Both formulas work for me.  Make sure on the SUMIF() you have `*` on both sides of the `Company`: `"*Company*"` If you are using a cell reference: `"*" & F2 & "*"`.  I noticed you are referring to two different sheets in the two formulas, make sure your references are correct.  Also your Column References in the SUMPRODUCT are shifted one and not the same size.

Comment: I knew I was missing something small!  Thanks.  Just adding the * on both sides solved it and making sure my column references were the same size.  Dumb mistakes will get you in Excel.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example that you can adapt.  It processes data in **A1** through **B5**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Company",A1:A5))*(B1:B5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping out!  Your formula works as well!